# Model Mapper populating value to wrong field during dto to entity conversion

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, modelmapper

I have an Entity called MasterEntity which has a unidirectional One to one relationship to another entity called ChildEntity as per below description, which are mapped to respective database tables.

```
    @Entity(name = "MasterEntity")
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MasterEntity {
 
        @id
        private Integer Id;
        private String Name;
        private String Division;

        @OneToOne
        @MapsId
        @JoinColumn(name = "Id")
        private ChildEntity childEntity;

    }

    @Entity(name = "childEntity")
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class ChildEntity {
 
        @id
        private Integer Id;
        private String MatchingName;

    }
```

And I have a MasterEntityDTO which has fields as below.

```
    @Builder
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MasterEntityDTO {
 
    private Integer Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Division;

    }
```

I try to map the dto object to the Entity using Model Mapper.
with Matching Strategy set to LOOSE since I plan to add additional fields to the DTO which map to childEntity

```
    masterEntityDTO.setName("Jonathan");

    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.LOOSE);

    modelMapper.map(masterEntityDTO, MasterEntity.class);
```

The Resultant entity which I get has following values.

```
Id = null
Name = "Jonathan"
Division = null
Id = null
MatchingName = "Jonathan"
```

so my field **MatchingName** is getting wrongly populated with the value of **Name** field.

I tried different configurations for the modelMapper but that is not solving the issue.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned in ModelMapper [documentation](https://modelmapper.org/getting-started/#handling-mismatches), in **Handling Mismatches**, section:

> While ModelMapper will do its best to implicitly match source and
> destination properties for you, sometimes you may need to explicitly
> define mappings between properties.
>
> ModelMapper supports a variety of mapping approaches, allowing you to
> use any mix of methods and field references.

So here in this case, you would need to define your custom mapping.

Or moreover you need to use [MatchingStrategies.Standard](http://modelmapper.org/user-manual/configuration/#matching-strategies), rather than Loose.